# Time difference between forEach() and forEachOrdered in parallel stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I made the following code.

```
    @Test
    public void parallelStream() {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0,10_000).boxed().parallel()
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void parallelStreamOrdered() {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0,10_000).boxed().parallel()
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }
```

As a result of the performance, parallelStream took 178 ms and parallelStreamOrder took 33 ms.

I know that in parallel, .forEach() is non-deterministic, and .forEachOrdered() is guaranteed order.

But is it related to speed? It was expected that keeping the order would slow down the speed.
I wonder why the speed is so different.

Comment: You are measuring the performance of an operation that doesn’t work in parallel at all, `System.out.println(…)` which is internally `synchronized`. The most efficient execution of this example would be single threaded, with all synchronizations merged. You are comparing the bad with the worse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should test this with some big value then the result would be much more clear and there will be a high time difference.